# open source license that forces changes back?

Tags: licensing

I don't want the GNU, and would like corporations to use the software, but if they modify the original software, I want the license to state that this must be posted back as well or put up on a website or something.

What open source license would meet that requirement?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the Mozilla and Eclipse Public License, or the LGPL (which is a little more aimed a C type early binding code...).  I think both MPL and EPL will allow people to use your code as a library, but require any changes to your code to be made open source.  IANAL.

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the Ecipse Public License that ensures modifications must be pushed to the web or published somewhere, etc.

Comment: Mozilla seems to work quite nicely, thanks.

Comment: actually, I reread the mozilla, I must have misread the first time.  IT forces modifications under the same license, but doesn't say they have to publish those modifications to the web or anywhere, does it?

Comment: You can also take a look at Wikipedia: "The MPL allows covered source code to be mixed with other files under a different, even proprietary license. However, code files licensed under the MPL must remain under the MPL and freely available in source form." - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Public_License  and the MPL FAQ referenced by hakre.

Comment: that is a good point, if they touch that file, it must remain under MPL...that is pretty good, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

A free software open source license that forces to give any kind of changes back does not exists. That actually is no wonder, because it would make the software non-free, you are telling somebody else what she/he must do with his/her changes. They do not own their changes any longer, they are not free with their changes any longer.

So you won't find such a license, it is against the principles of free and open source software.

Then you write you dislike GNU GPL. I don't want to trick you into something here, just to point out that actually from all open source licenses that are available, the GNU GPL is the most successful one to encourage those who extend and modify the software to contribute back their changes. Still there is no guarantee for that by the license itself, it's more the spirit it reflects so that changes keep on flowing around.

So actually no open source license does meet your requirement.

But the license that is most successful for what you aim for with your requirement is the one you do not want.

So it is not simple to answer your question and help you. Probably you can re-think a little with which dynamics of free and open source licensing you want to work with? It looks a bit to me you're looking for very strong copyleft, so normally I'd say the license you're looking for is the GNU Affero General Public License. However you write you dislike GNU. But actually for practical reasons I can not suggest you any GPL compatible copyleft license.

A non GNU copyleft license that is compatible with GNU licenses is the Mozilla Public License 2.0 (MPL-2.0). However it is a file-level copyleft license. For the reasons outlined above, it does allow to make modifications to the software if you just do not edit files but add files. These changes do not need to be provided in source-form, so there is no direct contribution back. Contributions to files under MPL however, need to be passed along in source-form to everybody who gets the work and demands the source-code. But as outlined above, there is no forcing that any changes need to be contributed *back*.

The [MPL 2.0 FAQ](http://www.mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/FAQ.html) is probably of more use for you to get some more help with your decision.

Comment: This is an incorrect statement "That actually is no wonder, because it would make the software non-free".  If the license where to say "Any modifications must be published on the web under the same license" then the software would STILL be free.  This also does not prevent commercial entity from using the software as they do not have to put their software on the web as they did not change the software(only modifications have to be published).  I heard there was such a license and would like to find that one.

Comment: oh, and ps, they do force any modifications under the same license here with this sentence(they just miss the you must publish modifications on the web part) .... "All distribution of Covered Software in Source Code Form, including any Modifications that You create or to which You contribute, must be under the terms of this License."

Comment: Non-free in the sense of *The Free Software Definition* and *The Debian Free Software Guidelines* (or the slight modification of the last one known as *The Open Source Definition*). If you force to give private changes back, a software is considered non-free. This has nothing to do with commercial (which does not mean much actually, commercial is only some detail and no FOSS license forbids commercial use) -- The second part you comment on are just clauses to make the terms reciprocal, which you find often (always) in copyleft licenses.

Comment: *"I heard there was such a license and would like to find that one."* I can understand your motivation but to the best of my knowledge no FOSS license exists for the said reasons. But do not count on my word only, get a second and third opinion on the topic as well.

Comment: AGPL could be seen as pretty much forcing publication (in some form) of changes.  I guess the question would be the notion of "distribution", that is AFAIK most open licenses allow me to make modifications and use the results myself without having to share the changes, its mostly if you distribute (in some form) the program that the licenses kick in as far as giving others access to your changes.

Comment: Any license with copyleft could be seen so. But it has nothing to do with forcing somebody. These licenses take care that the user who uses the software has the right to obtain its source. The focus is on the user of the software, not the original author. No forcing, giving. Copyleft not Copyright. And *all* free software licenses allow you to make changes to your software, because you have the right to obtain the source and to change it. Some of these licenses require that you can not restrict that right if you pass the software along. But you don't have to pass, there is no forcing to pass.